# Mk5 Golf in gear but won't move

Tags: vw, troubleshooting, manual-transmission, golf

I have a 2007 VW Golf 1.4 L, completely standard. All work that was done on it was by the main VW dealership.

I was taking off from a stop sign nice and gently in 1st gear and after 2 seconds all you could hear is the car revs increasing and speed reducing. I pushed the car into a car park and put it into every gear I could and all that happened each time I left off the clutch was nothing.

The car doesn't make any whining sound or noises of any kind and it doesn't pop it out of gear either. There was no sound or smell or smoke when the car lost driving capabilities.

Any help?

Comment: Sounds like clutch wore out or maybe the pressure in the system is gone. Start by checking if there's fluid in the reservoir

Answer (score 2):

This could be the clutch centre plate has failed : where the centre shears from the friction outer... This means gearbox out...

Or, a shaft has failed : possibly a driveshaft into one of the hubs or the output of the gearbox into the final drive.

Both mean you need a mechanic to look at it.